# Overridden standard "New" button is not showing in community

Tags: lightning-experience, button-overrides, lightning-community

We have one object whose standard "New" button has been overridden with visualforce page. It's working fine in Salesforce classic. I can see "New" button in related lists. In lightning community, i cannot see "New" button in related list. I tried to find the solution and i came to that lightning doesn't support overriden action buttons. So is there any way i can achive stadard new behaviour in lightning?

Comment: Do you get the answer?

Answer (score 2):

PLease implement lightning component with lightning:actionOverride and add your logic/URL there, then go to button and select lightning option then select your component

Answer (score 0):

- Verify that your Visualforce page is marked in Setup as `Available for Lightning Experience, Experience Builder sites, and the mobile app`
- Verify that the Experience user has Create CRUD permission on the object

[image]